# Predis ConnectionException: Connection timed out using on lumen api 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redis, lumen

I'm using laravel lumen api 5.6.3 for my application. I have also using Redis for my data storage. It's working fine last 2 years and past 10 days I'm getting issue like ERROR:

> Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: Connection timed out
>   [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] in
>   /home/minwin/public_html/winapi/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/minwin/public_html/winapi/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(128):
>   Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->onConnectionError('Connection
>   time...', 110) #1
>   /home/minwin/public_html/winapi/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(178):
>   Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->createStreamSocket(Object(Predis\Connection\Parameters),
>   'tcp://127.0.0.1...', 4) #2
>   /home/minwin/public_html/winapi/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(100):
>   Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->tcpStreamInitializer(Object(Predis\Connection\Parameters))

I have setting in .env like,

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis

CACHE_DRIVER=redis 
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Please help any one to solve this issue.

These response comes while I check grep command for redis,

> [root@host ~]# grep timeout /etc/redis.conf read_write_timeout -1
>    timeout 0
>    # The following option sets the replication timeout for:
>    # 2) Master timeout from the point of view of slaves (data, pings).
>    # 3) Slave timeout from the point of view of masters (REPLCONF ACK pings).
>    # specified for repl-ping-slave-period otherwise a timeout will be detected
>    # repl-timeout 60
>    # Cluster node timeout is the amount of milliseconds a node must be unreachable
>    # Most other internal time limits are multiple of the node timeout.
>    # cluster-node-timeout 15000
>    #   (node-timeout * slave-validity-factor) + repl-ping-slave-period
>    # So for example if node-timeout is 30 seconds, and the slave-validity-factor
>    # closing connections of clients in timeout, purging expired keys that are
>    # there are many keys expiring at the same time, and timeouts may be

Comment: is that on production, or local  ... ?  if local are you using docker ?  give us some more information about your dev environment .

Comment: This issue coming in production, I have hosted in liquid web linux hosting. I have installed Redis server v=3.2.10. I have updated result of grep timeout /etc/redis.conf